# Clamping a quaternion rotation causes shaking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the unity3D game engine. I have a player that is a cube with a rigidbody attached to it. Gravity is turned off, and angular drag is set to 0. I am rotating it use AddTorque, but I want to make sure that the x angle is never more than the rotationClampLow (currently at 45 degrees) and never less than rotationClampHigh (currently 315 degrees). So the x angle can be anything except for greater than 45 or less than 315.

This is the code I currently have:

```
 // rotationSpeed is a float currently set at 3.
 void RotatePlayer () {
    horizontalRotation = rotationSpeed * Input.GetAxisRaw("HorizontalRotate");
    verticalRotation = rotationSpeed * Input.GetAxisRaw("VerticalRotate");

    if ( horizontalRotation != 0 )
        Debug.Log("Horizontal rotation input: " + horizontalRotation);

    ClampPlayerRotation();

    rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    rb.AddTorque(horizontalRotation, verticalRotation, 0f, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}


void ClampPlayerRotation () {

    // I use 180 because it is halfway between 45 and 315
    if ( rb.rotation.eulerAngles.x >= rotationClampLow && rb.rotation.eulerAngles.x <= 180) {

        // Make sure that the x rotation isn't more than the low clamp
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(rotationClampLow, rb.rotation.eulerAngles.y, rb.rotation.eulerAngles.z);

        //Make sure no positive torque is added to the x axis
        if ( horizontalRotation > 0 )
            horizontalRotation = 0;
    }
    else if ( rb.rotation.eulerAngles.x <= rotationClampHigh && rb.rotation.eulerAngles.x > 180 ) {

        // Make sure that the x rotation isn't less than the high clamp
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(rotationClampHigh, rb.rotation.eulerAngles.y, rb.rotation.eulerAngles.z);

        //Make sure no negative torque is added to the x axis
        if ( horizontalRotation < 0 )
            horizontalRotation = 0;
    }
```

Currently when the x rotation reaches 45, the cube stops rotation, but when it reaches 315 it starts to jitter between 310 and 315 degrees. How can this problem be resolved? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: [Here is what is happening](http://gfycat.com/FlowerySlimyChicken)

Edit 2: RotatePlayer() is being called from FixedUpdate().

Edit 3: Changed code from:

```
rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(rotationClampLow, rb.rotation.eulerAngles.y, rb.rotation.eulerAngles.z));
```

To:

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(rotationClampLow, rb.rotation.eulerAngles.y, rb.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
```

Comment: Can you show from what method `RotatePlayer()` is being called from?

Comment: ah yes I knew I forgot something. Fixed Update().

Comment: never use FixedUpdate for any reason - ever

Comment: you rarely use quaternions for anything.  simply set the eulerAngles if needs be

Comment: @JoeBlow could you tell me why I shouldn't use FixedUpdate() ever? The docs clearly state it should be used for messing with rigidbodies. As for     `ridigbody.rotation.eulerAngles.x  = rotationClampLow;` it says I can't set it directly, so how do I go about with that?

Comment: @Poplop As for setting the eulerAngles he means `rb.rotation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(rotationClampLow, rb.rotation.eulerAngles.y, rb.rotation.eulerAngles.z)`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain hmm if I try that I get "Cannot modify the return value of 'Rigidbody.rotation' because it is not a variable."

Comment: it's transform.eulerAngles, Scott just accidentally typed rotation.  simply check the manual

Comment: Ah thanks. So code is cleaner now, but object still jitters.

Comment: did you try [rigidbody.AddTorgue](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html)?